# Get timetable of specific train stations from google maps Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps

I'm trying to extract the departure time and destination of the next trains leaving from the [Warszawa Śródmieście WKD](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Warszawa+%C5%9Ar%C3%B3dmie%C5%9Bcie+WKD/@52.227691,20.979799,14z/data=!4m8!3m7!1s0x471ecc926eda86fd:0xe3fd7feb0904bc79!6m1!1v1!8m2!3d52.22769!4d21.0004!16zL20vMGg0cF9f) station using Kotlin. I attempted to scrape the data using okHttp3, but I couldn't locate the necessary information about the trains departing from this station.

I tried this

```
val scheduleFetch = OkHttpClient()
        val request = Request.Builder()
            .url(scheduleUrl)
            .build()

        scheduleFetch.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                println("Faield to connect")
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                response.use {
                    val body = response.body
                    println(body?.string())
                }
            }
        })
```

i got source code but as i said i couldn't find data about leaving hour or destination of trains leaving